# Prolog - dividing a list in N parts

Tags: list, prolog, dcg, divide

I'm trying to write a predicate that divides a list into N parts. 
This is what I have so far.

```
partition(1, List, List).
partition(N, List, [X,Y|Rest]):-
    chop(List, X, Y),
    member(NextToChop, [X,Y]), %Choose one of the new parts to chop further.
    NewN is N-1,
    partition(NewN, NextToChop, Rest).

chop(List, _, _):-
    length(List, Length),
    Length < 2, %You can't chop something that doesn't have at least 2 elements
    fail,!.
chop(List, Deel1, Deel2):-
    append(Deel1, Deel2, List),
    Deel1 \= [],
    Deel2 \= [].
```

The idea is to keep chopping parts of the list into two other parts until I have N pieces.
I have mediocre results with this approach:

```
?- partition(2, [1,2,3,4], List).
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], 1] ;
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], 2, 3, 4] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], 1, 2] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], 3, 4] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], 1, 2, 3] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], 4] ;
false.
```

So I get what I want, but I get it two times and there are some other things attached. 
When dividing into 3 parts things get worse:

```
?- partition(3, [1,2,3,4], List).
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2], [3, 4], 2] ;
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2], [3, 4], 3, 4] ;
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [4], 2, 3] ;
List = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [4], 4] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1], [2], 1] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1], [2], 2] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3], [4], 3] ;
List = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3], [4], 4] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [1], [2, 3], 1] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [1], [2, 3], 2, 3] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 2], [3], 1, 2] ;
List = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 2], [3], 3] ;
false.
```

Another idea is using prefix but I don't know how that would really work. To use that I should be able to let Prolog know that it needs to take a prefix that's not too short and not too long either, so I don't take a prefix that's too long so there's nothing left for a next recursion step.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Little clarification: the predicate should return all posibilities of dividing the list in N parts (not including empty lists).

Comment: should the N parts have the same length? should the predicate return all possible ways you can divide the list in N parts?

Comment: @thanosQR: The predicate should return all possible ways you can divide the list in N parts. I'll add it to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the basic way I'd use to implement that (using `append/2` and `length/2`) :

```
list_n_parts(List, Parts, Result) :-
    length(Result, Parts),
    append(Result, List).
```

Now, that doesn't totally complies to your expectations : it allows for `[]`.

One idea to fix that is to use a `maplist` call to format the Resulting list beforehand :

```
list_n_parts(List, Parts, Result) :-
    length(Result, Parts),
```

using `copy_term/2`, the `maplist/2` call looks like :

```
    maplist(copy_term([_|_]), Result),
```

using `functor/3` (credits to @false), it would look like :

```
    maplist(functor('.', 2), Result),
```

using [lambda.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you could write :

```
    maplist(\[_|_]^true, Result),
```

since the '\' already performs a term copy (thanks @false).

The only thing left is the `append/2` call:

```
    append(Result, List).
```

Another idea would be to use `forall/2` filtering (maybe simpler to get, but worse in complexity) :

```
list_n_parts(List, Parts, Result) :-
    length(Result, Parts),
    append(Result, List),
    forall(member(X, Result), X \= []).
```

etc...

Comment: Ah damn, that just so simple I couldn't even get my mind around it. Thanks a lot! @mat 's solution is nice and clean too but it uses things I didn't see in my class so I'll use yours :)

Comment: @Mog: `maplist(\[_|_]^true, Result)` would describe the same as `maplist(\X^(copy_term([_|_], NotEmpty), =(NotEmpty, X)), Result)`. That is, the `\ ` alone already does a `copy_term`.

Comment: In **that** case, `maplist(functor('.',2), Result)` is still preferable by a very tiny margin.

Comment: @Mog: A pity you removed the lambda version alltogether.

Comment: I would remove the distracting comments - that are not interesting fo r others. Think of it: If someone will read this in 3 years. Also, do you know how to link from a program?

Comment: Yes - such that people get the library!

Answer (score 5):

When describing relations that involve lists, DCGs are often very useful. Consider:

```
list_n_parts(List, N, Parts) :-
        length(Parts, N),
        phrase(parts(Parts), List).

parts([]) --> [].
parts([Part|Parts]) --> part(Part), parts(Parts).

part([P|Ps]) --> [P], list(Ps).

list([]) --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_n_parts([1,2,3,4], 2, Ps).
Ps = [[1], [2, 3, 4]] ;
Ps = [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ;
Ps = [[1, 2, 3], [4]] ;
false.
```

Comment: I've seen DCG's in another class but never knew you could use those in Prolog. Your solution is pretty clean but since I didn't see DCG's in my Declarative Languages course I'll use @Mog 's solution. Thanks anyways, I learned about DCG in Prolog ^^